Interpretation of "right" and "left"
I have heard words like "this party is left" and "this party is right wing" being thrown about, but many people (including me) don't know exactly how to interpret "right" or "left"; whether those terms refer to political reforms (as relevant today) advocated by a party or to the ideology being promoted. The terms "right" and "left" seem to have different meanings depending on the perspective and the regional context.
We say that people who follow the ideology of Marxism, communism and socialism are left, and the Nazi (even though they had "socialist" in their name, which misleads some people) are perceived as representing the extreme right of the spectrum.
A European "right-wing" politician may be seen as centrist in America and a simply "left-leaning" politician in let's say China may seem extreme left to Americans.
So what I am essentially getting at is:

How are we able to throw these "left" and "right" terms about when we don't have a clear idea of what they even mean? Someone who hates "left" will consider everything he doesn't like about his party to be "left". So does that mean that what makes a party "left" is the reforms it advocates or its ideology?
I know this might sound philosophical, but why are the schools of thought of Marx and Lenin called left while others are right?

I know some people think this question is too trivial and not in need of an answer, but when someone one uses the words "left" and "right" I am doubt as to what they mean.
Edit: I know that during the French revolution these terms emerged from those to the left of the King being called "left" and those on the right being called "right", but "right" and "left" only came to be applied to the political spectrum during the 19th century because in the 18th century the "lefts" were moderates, not the "left" we think of today.

Think you are "mislead" about Nazis, they structurally joined left and right border of a preceding democratic sepctrum. Clamping of the Labor Party from NSD"AP" is not a correct display their origin. Again in the 70s the far left turned against the center "social democrates" and even formed a terror organization.

@SamGinrich No you seem to be very much mislead about the Nazis. They very much were a far right party, any resemblance of a left wing was a) powerless and b) literally purged when they took over government power. Also who is "the left" or "the far left" and you realize how many Nazis were still in official positions in post war Germany including the 70s?

@haxor789 Sorry, we don't continue on your level. I gave structural background of forces, which the Nazi movement was composed from and you understand nothing.

@SamGinrich You're spreading misinformation. Yes the NSDAP arose from the DAP which was a club of 1 guy (Anton Drexler) and his railroad worker buddies. Which was already influenced by a guy named Karl Harrer who worked for the Thule society (antisemitic secret society) to be an antisemitic alternative to actual labor parties, so the "D" in that party was already more than just a descriptor for "Germany" but an expression of "völkischer Nationalismus" (racist ethnonationalism). Then 9 month later a guy named Adolf Hitler joined, rivaled Harrer's idea of a secret society with a ...

@SamGinrich 2/ ... totalitarian mass organization. Hitler was initially not in the party leadership and adverse to the party democracy. He largely organized propaganda and mass events meaning he acquired members and money which meant after 3 month he transformed it into the NS-DAP and yet a year later he became it's leader. and that was 1921. So with Hitler the main focus was on populist antisemitism not the labor party and he ruled for essentially the entire time that the NSDAP/DAP had any relevance and there was no genuine leftist goals in that besides the name.

@haxor789 Socially the the Nazis were far right, economically the Nazis were collectivist. There was no control over private ownership during the times of National socialism, as described in depth by Pollock, Brüneck or even Mises.

@CuriousIndeed Yeah the Nazis privatized the economy:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Nazi_Germany#Privatization_and_business_ties and had no economic ideology beyond power and warfare: "Hitler believed that the lack of a precise economic programme was one of the Nazi Party's strengths, saying: "The basic feature of our economic theory is that we have no theory at all"" Not sure who the other 2 guys there are but wasn't Mises the guy who praised Mussolini's fascism?

@haxor789 Just read your own wikipedia article: "However, the privatization was "applied within a framework of increasing control of the state over the whole economy through regulation and political interference,"

@CuriousIndeed "The Nazi leadership believed that "private property itself provided important incentives to achieve greater cost consciousness, efficiency gains, and technical progress." Adolf Hitler used Social Darwinist arguments to support this stance, cautioning against "bureaucratic managing of the economy" that would preserve the weak and "represent a burden to the higher ability, industry and value.""
Also it's quite odd to make that about the economy when the Nazis didn't and when that was not top of their agenda. Like the economy much as everything else served their genocide plans.

@haxor789. There was competition within the framework commanded by the National Socialists. Nazi Germany was far away from a free market economy but not as restricted as Soviet Union. Pollock (himself a Neo-Marxist) described it as follows: "I believe it reaches far more deeply and should be described as the destruction of all the essential traits of private ownership, saving one exception." https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ecaf.12551 Pollock wrote in German, if you want to read the original I can DM you a copy. It's not odd at all and has been described by many cont. writers

@CuriousIndeed Which Pollock? Friedrich Pollock? Also that talk about economics is completely missing the point. In the political context "right wing" is authoritarian, chauvinistic, social darwinistic and hierarchical. And Hitler was pretty much all of that. And capitalism and it's proponents also check a lot of these boxes hence why they are usually grouped on the right. Now the U.S. as biggest advocate of capitalism tries a lot to rebrand and pretend right wing is just about free markets, but to apply those definitions to the Nazi era or any place outside the U.S. is bullshit.

@CuriousIndeed Like Capitalists see the inequality in society, shrug and call it "meritocracy", socialists call it plutocracy and try to dismantle it by taking ownership of the means of production. Fascists have no ideal of the economy, they just see a decline and attribute it to some scapegoat usually leftists, minorities or people not working hard enough. Which is what conservatives also preach all day long, just that they know it's bullshit, while fascists actually drink that kool-aid. Just squash [scapegoat] and everything will be better. Needless to say that's never how that works...

Yes Friedrich Pollock. "any resemblance of a left wing was a) powerless and b) literally purged when they took over government power:" The Nazis shared the same economic ideas as left-wing parties. That is an important and often overlooked fact. In fact many believe that the Nazis were capitalist, which is utterly wrong. That does not mean that the Nazis were a left-wing party ofc.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Words like "left" and "right" are words like "fast" and "slow".  They have meanings, but those meanings depend critically on the context, including the wider context in which they are placed.
So if I say "My car is fast" it is understood by reference to the culture and technological status that (you assume) I have.  If I took it to the race track, it might be considered "slow".
So words like "left" and "right" only make sense when spoken within a political culture.  This can cause surprises, since the collection of beliefs associated with "the right" in the USA may be very different from the set of beliefs associated with "the right" in the UK or Europe. Europe has past history of authoritarian government, so the conservative position tends towards authoritarianism.  The US has a history of a restricted federal government, so the "conservative" position tends towards libertarianism.
We are able to use these words because they are understood within a particular culture.  We sometimes expect the words to carry the same meaning outside our own culture, but as illustrated above, we can be misunderstood if we use them with speakers from other political cultures.
The tendency in each political culture is to for parties to form that oppose each other. These parties got labeled "left" and "right".  Over time the parties evolve and other parties in other cultures form. Other parties get labelled "left" and "right" based on analogies.  So the parties of Lenin, which shared similarities with the communist parties in England and Germany, which shared similarities with the radical parties in the French revolution which were labelled as "left".  Hence the party of Lenin is also labelled "left", even if the actually policies of his party are quite different from those of revolutionary France.

If you want to dive down into the philosophical nuts and bolts, the difference between 'Right' and 'Left' in sociopolitical discussions is that Rightists invariably defend, promote, or advocate hierarchical forms of social order, while Leftists defend, promote, or advocate egalitarian forms of social order. Back in the French revolution this meant that those who still supported the aristocracy and monarchy sat on the right, while those seeking some republican form of government sat on the left.
Of course, the nature of hierarchical or egalitarian forms has evolved over time. Rightists in the Western world have largely given up on monarchical or aristocratic hierarchies, and instead reach for hierarchies based on:

military or civil police forces (kratocracy)
religion (theocracy or ecclesiocracy)
wealth (plutocracy or corporatocracy)
social standing (timocracy, demagogracy, or ethnocracy)

Modern Leftists, by contrast, generally see the old republican forms as (at best) a compromise with entrenched power groups, and look instead for egalitarian systems based on:

wealth leveling (socialism, communism, etc)
expansion and universalization of human rights (social liberalism and
democratic socialism)
strengthening of political institutions (democracy or cultural
liberalism)

But all-in-all the distinction between hierarchical and egalitarian forms of government defines the Right/Left distinction.

In the United States, there are a bundle of policy positions routinely understood to be "right" and the opposite positions are routinely understood to be "left". For example, right-wingers are pro-life, anti-gun control, pro-free market, skeptical of environmental regulation, etc. Left-wingers are pro-abortion, pro-gun control, pro-socialism, enthusiastic about environmental regulation, etc.
Why do these positions go together? In some cases one could identify a common thread, but for the most part, it's pretty hard to say. They just ... tend to go together.
Of course "right" and "left" are relative terms. As you said in your post, what is considered "far left" in the US would probably be considered "moderate" in China, etc. But this is hardly startling. If I said that an animal is "really big", how you interpret that statement depends a lot on what sort of animal we are talking about. A small elephant is bigger than a large hamster. So sure, the meaning of the terms has to be taken in context of time and place.
People sometimes say that liberals favor change while conservatives favor the status quo. But such a definition is not just inaccurate but useless. Suppose it is true at a certain point in time. Then liberals win a few elections and put their policies into place. Now it is liberals who want to keep the status quo and conservatives who want change.
In the US today, conservatives are calling for major changes to social security and medicare, while liberals insist that we dare not meddle with these programs but must keep them essentially as is. Some extreme conservatives have even called for replacing the police with private police forces. Liberals oppose this precisely on the grounds that it is a new and untested idea. That is, on many issues, liberals are defending the status quo and conservatives are calling for change.
Likewise, some have said that conservatives support authoritarianism while liberals support a more free-wheeling system. But in 21st century America one could well argue that the opposite is the case. It is liberals who say that the government should monitor the Internet and block "misinformation", while conservatives are calling for free and open debate.
So I am hard pressed to name some underlying guiding principle that ties together all the positions of left-wingers or all the positions of right-wingers. Other than a circular argument that left-wingers hold these positions because they are all left-wing, and similarly for right-wingers. At least, not without getting into value judgements. (Like, "people on my side advocate positions based on rational thought while our opponents rely on emotion", or "our side values freedom and justice while our opponents defend intolerance and bigotry".)
Just BTW, the Nazi called themselves "socialist" because their policies were socialist. They favored government control of industry, government control of education, government running the pension system, etc. See Hitler's 25 Points speech. If you're a socialist and you don't like Nazis, you can certainly disavow Hitler, but you can't rationally say he wasn't a socialist.
Oh, as to where the terms "left" and "right" came from ... In the parliament of 18th century France, the conservatives sat on the right and the liberals sat on the left. The terminology has carried over from there.

"the Nazi called themselves "socialist" because their policies were socialist."  Nazi was a derogatory name.   They did call themselves Socialists because to the German ear that as moderate left or liberal.   That changed in 1934 prior to Hitler coming to power.   The night of the long knives.   Hitler betrayed the populist wing (SA brown shirts) of his own party as the price to be paid for German military support for his entering government.  After the purge what remained was Hitler chancellor for life, his war machine, and his alliance with German elites to avenge WWI and genocide.

@JMS no idea, how this would respond to question or answer.

Hmmm, upvoted, because of some very good points but the Nazi analysis is sketchy.  NASDP was chosen early on as a branding change from its predecessor party and it is unclear how "socialist" it was meant to be.  Remember that the Nazi party was "sold" to industrialists and the army as a means to oppose Communism.  And Hitler purged Strasser for being too socialist.  The nazis were control freaks, esp. later, but mostly due to totalitarianism, rationing raw materials and propaganda, less for redistributive reasons.

An example of the arbitrariness of bundle of policy positions routinely understood would be anti-vax sentiments.  In pre-Covid days, this was related to measles and autism conspiracy theories and those, I believe, were more or less equally distributed along the Rep/Dem - right/left spectrum.  Covid brought in big govt vs business, health regulations vs economic activity and... presto:  anti-vaccers are now deemed rightwing.

In the link  below some reasons are listed, why the NSDAP was a socialist party. There are many other reasons not mentioned, f.e. the standard products realized or planned (Volkswagen, Volkskuehlschrank, Volksempfänger, Volksappartment, mass holiday resorts like in Prora -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prora, etc.) or the many laws that are typical demands/concepts of socialist parties.
https://wie24-com.translate.goog/nazis-links/?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp
(Allow some seconds for translation).

@xeeka Or http://johansens.us/sane/politics/nazi-right.htm

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Yes, certainly the Nazis were anti-communist. At that time, communists advocated a world government and abolition of independent nations. A communist world government, of course. The Nazis were NATIONAL socialists. They wanted socialism/communism but they also wanted to preserve independent nations. Nazis and communists hated each other because communists wanted to destroy national governments and the Nazis wanted to prevent a world government. They had similar policies, but very different ideas about who should be in charge.

@JMS Yes back in those days "socialist" was a much more commonplace term, there were was even an openly operating communist party, there head been socialist/communist and anarchist soviet republics, so the spectrum of the Overton window was much broader. Though fact wise Hitler took power in 1933 and the night of long knives came afterwards. The SA was his paramilitary thug army, but being leader and commander of the real army there was no longer a necessity for brawling street fighters, he could just make laws and sent the regular cops. Especially if the SA could demand compensation and power

@Jay If you want to add to your answer, do it in your answer but quoting your own website as source for your claims is really dishonest. Also the 25 point program was largely drafted by Draxler the guy who founded the DAP, while Hitler's reworked that party into the NSDAP and largely interpreted anticapitalism as antisemitism. Not to mention that even the original claims such as bringing exploiters and exploited together was a pretty uncommon claim for socialists.

@haxor789 I referred to my own web site rather than repeating everything I said there. Would it be more "honest" to repeat something I already said? Why?

@Jay Do I really have to explain to you that a link is most likely going to be understood as a source for a claim and not just as yourself making your own argument a lot longer but as unsubstantiated as ever? Now the concept of self-referencing yourself is not inherently dishonest but the way of just dropping a link definitely is.#

@haxor789 My argument was not "unsubstantiated". In the linked page I link to the text of the speech. What more substantiation about the content of a speech could one possibly ask for than a transcript of the speech? You are demonstrating your own bias when you dismiss a page that discusses a speech and links to a transcript of the speech as "unsubstantiated".

@Jay No you don't. You already linked to a translation in of the program in your answer, in that link you just provide your own, much to favorable, summary of it. Not even a reference to the original and definitely not a transcript of a speech. Also you ignored that this program was not crafted by Hitler and that it was largely irrelevant in the political theory and praxis. Hitler made it unalterable and altered it, but mostly changed the tone by his speeches by interpreting things antisemtic rather than socialist. And to call his nationalism "patriotic" is a massive understatement...

@haxor789 Oh, I'm sorry, you're right. I was thinking I had linked to a transcript but when I look back I see that I did not. I should update that page to include such a link.

In any case, it's easy enough to find a transcript on the Web. In any case, whether Hitler really "believed in" the statements he made in this speech or it was all just political posturing for the audience ... you could ask that about any speech given by any politician. The Nazi Party under Hitler did indeed carry out many of the policies described in this speech. So what, exactly, is your objection to what I said? What did I say that isn't true? "I don't like the implications" is not at all the same as "it's not true".

@Jay First of all you make claims of socialism meaning government intervention. That's an incorrect definition of socialism as that applies to all states in existence anywhere. 2nd of all you claim that the 25 point program was Hitler's and was relevant. It was neither. The initial party that Hitler co-opted was a guy and his railroad worker buddies which already had a crude political agenda with nationalism, antisemitism and some weird version of socialism that ignores the situation of the workers and instead focuses on national unity of exploiters and exploited.

@Jay Hitler than took that program and interpreted all of these points antisemitically while dropping any economic ideology working closely with industrialists and affirming private ownership and interest taking while having a program that says the opposite. Even rolling out a large privatization campaign once in office.

@haxor789 So the gist of your argument is, I don't like Hitler, therefore it is unfair to compare policies I support to Hitler's policies. "socialism meaning government intervention" Umm, yes. That's pretty much the definition of socialism. Socialists advocate "communal" control of the means of production, with the will of the community expressed through government.

Anyway, you're trying to turn on a discussion about DEFINITION of right vs left into a political debate about which is better. People have been debating that for decades and we're not going to resolve it here. Feel free to get the last word, I'm not going to engage further in a hopeless debate.

@Jay Well yes this shorting of "The Nazis had socialist in the name therefore the Nazis are socialists/left" is a common form of associating what you don't like with something that nobody really likes. And it's historically wrong. Like as said, those parts didn't come from the actual Nazis but the party that they coopted and had little to no influence on their actual platform apart from the nationalism and antisemitism already contained. They use very U.S. centric definitions of socialism that are simply distortions and present them with a certainty not warranted by actual facts.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@haxor789,  Hitler became chancellor of Germany in 1933.   Yet his party did not hold the majority nor even the important roles in the German government.   The government was a unity government and the real power broker was the vice chancellor, Franz von Papen.   Hitler would take over the government and declare himself dictator of Germany for life August 1934.   The night of the long knives June 30-July 2, purged the Brown shirts, people's army, or working blue color socialists from Hitler's party.  It was a price Hitler paid for support of the German military for his ascendency to real power

@JMS That's a mix of half-truths, but mostly inaccurate. The thing is democracy in Germany took a hard hit with the election of Paul van Hindenburg to the position of president in 1925 and from 1930 onward parliamentary majorities were no longer a necessity for the government. Instead there were presidential cabinets. Presidential_cabinets_of_the_Weimar_Republic Essentially the president appointed a government, the parliament objected rather sooner than later, the president dissolved parliament and in the mean time between re-elections the government ruled by presidential emergency decrees.

@JMS 2/ So yes Hitler never achieved a parliamentary majority in a free and fair election, though neither did his predecessors. In fact the cabinets of von Papen and von Schleicher ("von" denoting German nobility) consisted almost entirely of former aristocrats who have never been elected by anyone and weren't even part of a party that participated in elections. So no a lack of a majority was not an issue. So Papen had already tried to seize power and failed so yes he massively supported Hitler but stayed largely in the background.

@JMS 3/ But while his role in Hitler's ascend to power is pretty significant you should not overstate his power. Hitler was appointed chancellor 30th of January 1933, on 1st of February Hindenburg dissolved parliament and on the 4th of February Hitler got his first degree limiting freedom of assembly, freedom of the press and campaign financing as well as buffing police powers and the power of the federal government to enforce these things. After the burning of the parliament building he got another one further limiting civil liberties and increasing powers of the federal government

@JMS 4/ Both of them increasing the power of the government while making political campaigning more or less illegal before the upcoming general elections (of parliament) on March 5th 1933. And while the Nazis got to increase plurality they still not reached a majority which is why Hitler coerced the members of parliament into signing the enabling act on March 28th 1933. Which gave Hitler the legal right to pass laws without asking parliament or the president for approval. Essentially marking his ascend to dictatorship just 2 months after taking office.

@JMS 5/ And yes von Papen was apparently a major influence on Hindenburg to sign these decrees, but after having enabled those decrees he basically stripped Hindenburg and in consequence himself of pretty much all of his power. As vice-chancellor he would have been supposed to be prime minister of Prussia, but already on the 7th of April again 1933 Hitler assigned that role to Göring instead. And while at that point all of these acts and decrees were more or less shenanigans. The reason why Hitler was appointed in the first place was...

@JMS 6/ ... That Papen/Schleicher/Hindenburg ran the numbers and figured out that their Reichswehr connections would be sufficient to win a civil war against the Nazis, communists and social democrats and so they tried to align themselves with the faction most promising in numbers and most aligned with their own authoritarian values hence the fascists. But at this point they had given them the numbers, the power and the legitimacy. So even a Reichswehr coup d'etat would have little chances of success.

@JMS 7/ So before the night of long knives Hitler had more than a year to further consolidate his power, spread uninterrupted propaganda and purge dissent from outside and making his party even more of a force not to mess with. So by the time he purged his own peer he had probably already removed them from power and drawn other sources of power such as police,SS, Gestapo, Reichswehr, etc. von Papen was for example already superfluous beyond making PR for the Nazis and afterwards was made a diplomat and removed even further from power.

@JMS So making himself "Führer" and officially merging the offices of head of state and head of government after Hindenburg's death was more of a symbolic act. He probably could have killed HIndenburg earlier, but having a senile war hero making his peace with Hitler and approving him was probably more valuable. Also he took until 1943 to make himself dictator for life previously he extended the state of emergency for 4 years every 4 years. Though after 1933 that was more of a formality as you might have guessed.

@haxor789,  Declaring himself dictator for life Aug 19, 1934.  wasn't a symbolic act.   When Hitler became Chancellor Jan 1933, the Nazi's only had 3 of 13 ministries/cabinet offices. Yes from Jan 33 through Aug 34 Hitler would consolidate power.  Field Marshal Hindenburg who was supported by the German Military died Aug 2, 1934.  With support of the German Military Hitler declared himself dictator Aug 19.  Purging the brown-shirts during the night of the long knives, was the cost of gaining the military's support, the last organization in Germany which could have stood against Hitler.

@hoxor789,  In 1933-1934 it wasn't 87 year old Field Marshal Hindenburg who was holding back the Nazi's from dissolving the republic.   It was clearly his strong support in the military which the Nazi's were hesitant to directly challenge.  When the Military agreed to support Hitler after Hindenburg's imminent death;  that's when Hitler truly came to power,  and declaired himself dictary / leader / Fuhrer for life.

@JMS 1/ I don't know where you got this wild mix of half-truths from, but your narrative doesn't line up with the facts and I'm not sure to what end you're pushing it. Like Hindenburg wasn't "supported by the military", Hindenburg had at the end of WWI BEEN the military. He was the last leader of the OHL (military high command) that had the effective dictatorship of Germany during the later stage of the war and given that he was one of the few generals to win their battles (against Russia) he became a centerpiece of far right propaganda, hero worshiping etc.

2/ He had also been an aristocrat (the "von" implies nobility and the last name is usually the region that they owned) and an outspoken monarchist and anti-democrat. He sabotaged the governments and from 1930 onward, helped conservative governments without a parliamentary majority to side step democracy and elections by letting them rule via emergency decrees rather than by getting laws through parliament. Keeping the republic on the brink of revolution and allowing the far right and far left to flourish with this dysfunctional system.

3/ in 1932 Hindenburg ran again for president but this time against Hitler, so the far right fascist Hindenburg became the lesser of two evils and got a second term. He then planned with his military buddies to take over government and suspend elections altogether rather than playing this game of voting a parliament disbanding it and having an "intermediate" government ruling without any mandate or majority other than a backing of the president. But his military friends told him he wouldn't be able win a civil war against nazis, socialist, communists and even some conservatives.

4/ So Hindenburgs aristocratic and military buddies crafted the plan to support this Hitler guy, who had a low but significant plurality and was also anti-semitic, anti-democratic and ultra-nationalistic like they themselves. He also had once done a putsch with the first quartermaster general who had served directly with Hindenburg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_Hall_Putsch though that and another failed uprising of the military https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapp_Putsch kinda ruined his reputation, but Hitler was no stranger to these people.

5/ So the point upon which Hitler really got the approval of the military, aristocratic and conservative establishment was prior to JAN 1933 and culminated in von Papen talking to Hindenburg to make this Hitler guy chancellor. They already tried that prior, but Hindenburg didn't like this low rank nobody and while they already made concessions to Hitler for their plan, their plans often failed so Hitler got progressively better deals through no fault of his own. So 1933 is the lead up to Jan, 30, 1933 is when the far right establishment gave their official approval.

6/ And while Hitler only got 3/14 cabinet positions (chancellor, so head of all ministries), interior and an unassigned +1. He got an important one: police. Which kinda hints at how socialist he was not going for economy, social security, agriculture, labor, etc. no he instead went for power. Centralizing it for the federal government (which he oversaw) banning the opposition and being able to turn a blind eye to the terror of the SA against the opposition. Which as long as "the opposition" where communists and social democrats, the conservatives approved of.

7/ So within the course of 2 month he used that fight against the communists to gain legislature allowing him to suppress the press and major civil liberties that would allow to organize against him, the ability to make laws without parliament, the centralization of the police state. And he established a secret state police (GESTAPO) as well as creating a ministry for propaganda. For the most part the establishment approved of all of these things because that was also what they would have done... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_Revolution Non-nazi-fascism if you like.

8/ Though with every step the fascist conservatives not only purged the rights of the communists but also to the public made concessions towards their own rights. Like at this point Hitler could legally make laws and had the effective means to enforce them, while a Reichswehr uprising would be a coup, which had previously failed and didn't have public support. Not to mention that in raw numbers the regular army was restricted by the allies to 100.000 men while the party army of the Nazis had already 400.000 men in 1932.

@JMS 9/ Now obviously the Reichswehr was lying to the allies about their numbers and the army might still have better equipment than the paramilitaries (even though they might already have army supply to side step the restrictions). But still the odds of winning that civil war weren't great. Especially if the Nazis control police and propaganda and can frame the more or less already unpopular elites as traitors. So at that point the Nazis firmly controlled the law and weren't relying on the military to support them. On the contrary.

@JMS 10/ What makes the night of long knives significant is that the Nazis had consolidated power so much that they were able to go beyond the law and kill without appearing to be the bad guys just by claiming to suppress a coup. At that point everyone knew nobody would is truly save. Hitler also used that to get rid of the SA leadership which basically controlled another army and thus appeased the old elite while keeping them the SA and the SS in check with each other. So no that power grab happened much earlier.

@haxor789,   No! What makes the night of the long knives significant is that it was the price for securing the support of the German Reichswehr.  They were the only existential threat to Hitler's rule and the only thing left securing the Weimar Republic.   Once they pledged their support to Hitler, that is when Hitler truly came to power and announced himself Leader for life.  As for Hitler being able to kill folks and being above the law,  4 police officers died in the Beer hall Putsch in Nov 1923, Hitler served 9 months.  Clearly, he was above the law long before entering government.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Edit I know that during french revolution those terms emerged that the left of the kings were called left and at the right were called right but the concept of actual "right" and "left" truly came into political spectrum during 19th century because in the 18th century the "lefts" were moderist not the "left" we perceive today

Not quite. It's the sitting order in the French National Assembly. Apparently the king could order a meeting of the people called "estates general" where members of the 3 estates (castes: clergy, nobility, peasantry (everyone else)) would meet and discuss. Though despite the 3rd estate being by far the largest, their political power was by far the smallest. So shortly prior to the revolution the 3rd estate said basically fuck that and made their own assembly called the national assembly. Over time more people from the other estates joined that one while the king would have tried to shut it down and instead bring things back to the Estate General or even a Royal Seance (royal meeting), he failed and the gathering of troops and the proposal to hold the national assembly else where in between two armies, outraged them even further and so the revolution commenced:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Assembly_(French_Revolution)
So the sitting order of the national assembly has nothing to do with the king or kings (afaik there was just one), but instead marks the difference from the previous sitting order based on caste to one based on shared opinion. And this ordering led to 2 broad factions gathering in different parts of the room, on the right the royalists and on the left the revolutionaries (which at first weren't even republican but rather in favor of a constitutional monarchy, it was only after a failed coup and the execution of the king that things went republican).
And similar dynamics can be found in many parliamentary democracies. On top of that you had attempts to structure that ideologically, so in terms of what these two factions were for or against.
So you ended up with royalist vs republican, liberal vs authoritarian, order vs freedom, egalitarian vs elitist, progressive vs conservative aso. Essentially left-right marks the two ends of a mutually exclusive spectrum and as such it can be used for a whole bunch of different spectra in different places and eras.
The most common attempt at a universal left-right spectrum is one concerning social hierarchies:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left%E2%80%93right_political_spectrum
So the rejection of social hierarchies is left and the approval or tolerance of social hierarchies is right. Now the ordering factor for the hierarchies may vary drastically: power, hereditary, religion, income/wealth, means of production, race, sex, sexuality, gender, nationality, culture, education, ...
Which leads to an odd situation where there are countless of "right"-wing ideologies, that often are mutually exclusive and sometimes overlapping sometimes opposed to each other, like a capitalist wouldn't let racism get in the way of a good deal, while a racist doesn't bother with free trade, but might enjoy it if wealth inequality serves as de facto caste system where their race is better off.
But only 1 left wing. As all egalitarian ideas would collapse into one. Though if you don't fully go all the way you could still end up with a plethora of "leftists" (when compared to people even more in favor of social hierarchies), which all disagree on which hierarchy to keep for now. Even worse if they are radically for dismantling one sort of hierarchy but end up ignoring or even enhancing another hierarchy. Then they are technically "radically" "left" but not really "radically left" and depending on what gets the better of them, they might even enhance a hierarchy so far that they should more aptly be placed on the right side of the spectrum.
Like take Stalin or whatnot, if we give him the benefit of the doubt in terms of wanting to implement communism, he'd be hard left, you know egalitarian system, no state authority, common ownership of the communities resources by direct democratic means, sounds pretty anti-hierarchical and thus leftists. While if you look at what he actually did. You see hierarchies of party membership and function in the political, the economic and even the other social domains up to being on par or more authoritarian with the monarchical system that they tried to replace, which would logically render them far right.
Now with the Nazis it's a lot simpler, they just lied or creatively redefined what "socialism" means for them. So the confusion about their choice of words stems from the fact that you have a definition of these words in mind, while they soaked all of these ideas in an exclusionary racism and a theory of social darwinism and a leaders cult, so that the end result has nothing to do with the words that you think you're familiar with. Essentially they just used the buzz words of their time to catch the gullible and hoped nobody would find out that the end result is the polar opposite of what these words indicate.
So they are far right and didn't even try to hide that, subjugation of whom they considered inferior was their openly stated goal.
Though stating their goal that openly is kind of an oddity in the Western world after the French Revolution. Because the fact that republicans and democrats managed to reorganize the state without turning the world into a living hellscape, while the far right has managed to do just that, has for a long time pretty much made actual right wing politics pretty unpopular.
So even the parties that are right-wing so in favor of social hierarchies and throwing other social groups under the bus for their own benefit ended up having to utilize leftist lingo of equality and freedom in order to appeal to majorities, as elitists kinda struggle in democracies.
So ironically lots of far right and even neo-fascist parties speak of "liberty" or use "equality of opportunity vs equality of outcome" to present discrimination not as inequality (which would be unpopular) but as the result of a fair competition (even if that competition is never fair to begin with, if the "outcome" is healthcare and education, which for most isn't so much a goal, but a necessity for a fair competition to begin with).
So muddying the water is often a deliberate technique to avoid unpopular labels. Another is to position oneself in the middle. As that gives off vibes of "neutrality" and "best of both worlds", while in reality it mostly serves to not being held accountable when failing leftist goals or not having them in the first place, which is then branded as "realism", "realpolitics", "pragmatism" aso. Also while left and right are identifiable, the center is an entirely different topic as it's impossibly hard to tell where the center is. Also it's technically hard to be deliberately "centrists" as there's no real ideology in which that makes sense. Like either you want more/all people to participate in the decision making process or you want that to be exclusive, but so many and not more is ... weird.
So telling if a foreign party is left or right is difficult but probably still a lot easier than to tell what a local reporter means by "centrist".
In that domain you're likely referring to relative differences and relative differences with regards to specific topics. Like apparently comedians in the U.S. already joke that the people that newscasters call "moderate republicans" are only moderate compared to Trumpists who don't even accept election results or challenge them before they even happened or regardless of evidence just for the sake of taking power by any means possible.
Meaning the "moderate" and "centrist" refers not to the absolute spectrum (where it's already hard enough to be located), but to the center of the overton window of acceptable ideas in the public discourse and where that position can be changed and repositioned by the most extreme positions that get media coverage and are thus within the accepted political ideas.

In modern times, left and right varies a lot from country to country, and it tends to change a lot over time. However, there is a general trend that is followed almost everywhere.
The left is overall "Care" focused. They are generally extremely empathetic and tend to fight for policies that benefit who they see as the underdog. They also tend to have little empathy for who they see as the top dog, and this usually manifests in policies that transfers resources from the top dog to the underdog, or policies that protect the underdog from the top dog.
The right is overall "Order" focused. They generally believe that "Care" can't be chased directly, due to resulting in counterproductive incentives, and that a well organized society will benefit everyone, including the most needy. They tend to care less about who is on the top and who is on the bottom, and focus more on establishing an environment where productive behavior is encouraged, and unproductive ones are discouraged.
So while the left focuses more on things such as direct assistance, inclusivity, "free" essential services, safety nets, justice (for the underdog) etc... the right focuses more on law enforcement, economic policy, immigration policy, fiscal responsibility, etc...
Other political aspects such as freedom vs authority, nationalism vs internationalism, progress vs conservation, environmentalism vs industrialism, democracy vs autocracy etc... tend to either be present on both sides or switch sides from region to region and time to time, depending on how they interact with the aforementioned values.
Also, even the core values are sometimes abandoned for short term gains, electoral advantage, donor pressure, corruption, etc...


Question:
Interpretation of "right" and "left", many people(including me) doesn't know exactly how do we interpret "right" or "left" if it is based on their political reforms.

Short Answer:

Conservative the moderate right leaning philosophy wants to preserve the status queue as they see it.  They want to return to the good old days.  When that was varies.  When faced with a problems they want to either go back to what has worked before or tweak the existing to work.  Their solutions are generally safe, well understood.
Liberals, socialists the moderate left leaning philosophy generally entertain new untried solutions hoping for a home run.  Their solutions can be great, but are inherently more dangerous as they are untried.
You need both to have a functioning government with any sort of longevity.  Conservatives keep the lights on and make things run.  Liberals introduce new ideas as society changes.  Both have their roles to play, which is in the ascendency is generally a factor of when their antisepsis was in the ascendency for some length of time.
Answer
Simply Put, it is a relative political spectrum which uses where people find inspiration for their solutions to their problems.  When faced with a problem, a right or conservative leaning person will tend to fall back to solutions which have worked in the past.  A known solution.  Conservative solutions tend to be safe, well understood, but also compromises as there was likely a reason the solution was abandoned in the first place.  Still safe, well understood solutions are often the best solution.
A left leaning or liberal when faced with a problem tend to seek new solutions.  These solutions are inherently less understood and therefore more dangerous than conservative solutions because they are new.
Most people are moderates and employ both methods.  The strength of conservative approach is it's reliability; the weakness is for systemic problems like civil rights, slavery, climate change or the healthcare crisis where there are no traditional solutions, conservatives have no contribution but to maintain the current path.   The strength of the liberal approach is sometimes new approaches can provide a real and significant benefit especially for systemic problems; the weakness is often new solutions fail outright or make things worse.
Really to have a functioning government or organization you need both types of thinkers.
I say "relative" political position because over history the issues change it's where the decision makers find their inspiration which remains constant.  The Roman Senator Cato was said to be a conservative because at the dawn of the Roman Empire he advocated for the republic.  Stick with what's worked, conservative.  Thomas Paine is said to be a liberal because during the French Revolution he advocated for a Republic when historically the French had been governed under Monarchy.  Both advocated for Republic but relative to their place in history one was looking back the other was advocating for something new.
A lot of folks will argue that the left and right political system which was first coined in the early 1800's during the French Republic should not be used rather they advocate for a two or even three-dimensional grid system.  However, the left and right, liberal and conservative political spectrum is the most widely used political system in use today; so it's important to know what it means.

From Comments.


from: Jay  It's not my point here to debate who is right and who is wrong, or which policy is better. Just to say that the idea that conservatives want to keep the status quo and liberals want change is too simplistic to be useful. In many cases, conservatives want change and liberals want to keep the status quo.


As I have consistently said neither philosophy is devoid of really bad ideas, and to have a functioning government with any sort of longevity you need both types of thinkers.  Moderate, conservative ideas are often the better ideas due to being better understood, there are huge notable exceptions to that generality.

As for being "too simplistic to be useful".  It is a categorization, and a way to understand the meaning behind various decisions and labels.   As I've said it is the most used political spectrum today understanding what it means thus has value just on that basis alone.



From: Jay
... thousands of years. Like privatizing police forces. Liberals have replied that this is a dangerous idea precisely because it is untested and untried.  ( meaning it's a new idea conservatives are for and liberals are against? )

Untested and untried in the 21st century perhaps. There is a long history of private police forces in the United States and historically. Not too long ago that the Pinkertons, a private police force; had more men and arms than the US army, and big business used them to break unions, suppress workers and kill folks.

1892 Homestead Strike  3000 Pinkerton's traveled by barge and openned fire on striking steel mill workers.

1921 Battle of Blair Mountain, - the largest labor uprising in United States history and is the largest armed uprising since the American Civil War.  10,000 coal miner's vs 3,000 private security.

1932 Ford Massacre,  Planned as a peaceful march from Detroit into Dearborn by Union organizers, ending at the Rouge Plant employment office. The march was brutally suppressed by Henry Ford's private security, with five marchers killed and dozens injured by machine gun fire.


So privatizing the police isn't a new idea in the United States, these are a few of the more disastrous results.

from: prosfilaes "a right or conservative leaning person will tend to fall back to solutions which have worked in the past." It sounds good, but it doesn't correspond well to how the words are used in the real world. For example, the US Right is creating laws about abortion that have little relation to anything historical, which never (to my knowledge) worried about women crossing state lines to get an abortion. Likewise, unions are left in the US, despite the fact that they're a long-time solution that was big in the "Good Old Days" (1940s-1960s). –

When you are talking conservatism, it has everything to do with history.  Historically in the U.S abortion law was left up to the states until 1973.  In 1910 every state in the country had outlawed abortion.  That is exactly the conservative agenda now in 2024.  In Arizona they even reinstituted the anti abortion law from the 1800's.  So we are literally going back to the way the law worked prior to Roe vs Wade, and we are literally reinstituting the problems associated with that historic ban, using the same state driven strategy.  Nothing more conservative than that.

unions are left in the US, despite the fact that they're a long-time solution that was big in the "Good Old Days" (1940s-1960s).

No conservative would call the 40's - 60's the "good old days".  The 30's, 40's were dominated by Liberals.  FDR, Truman forever changed the way things worked in the US.  Typically conservatives see the good old days as the 1880's - 1900's when we had unregulated capitalism before T Roosevelt.  Or 20's 30's prior to Franklin Roosevelt.
Prior to the 40's - 60's "good old days" there were the days 1880's - 1920's when employers killed workers trying to unionize.  Carnigies Homestead strike mascre,  blair mountain massacre, and when Henry Ford's union busters machine gunned their striking workers.   The years when wealth was consolidated among a few, and Carnigies steal works lost 9% of their workforce annually related to on the job related deaths.  Very profitable for the businesses, and change was forced upon them by unions and sympathetic politicians.  Going back to those "good old days", by weakening government regulation, weakening unions is exactly going back to the past.
This is not to suggest that conservatism is not super valuable or always wrong.  It is just as likely that liberals go to far.  You need both, and after a long period of one being in the ascendency, shifting to the alternative provides a valuable correction be it liberal or conservative.

From: BlackJack
I have a problem with your right = conservative and left = liberal approach because that's exactly what confuses people who are used to political systems where the right is more liberal and the left more authoritarian.

I don't know what you mean. Perhaps communist china?  Where liberal and conservatism both work under a the overarching communist header because no other system of government nor political phylosophy are legally permitted to exist.  Liberal communists in china embraced free market, something new.  More conservative communists are now trying to roll back some of those free market reforms?  Is that what you mean?
Personally the definitions are from the Oxford dictionary and they work across political systems.

Also conservative solutions that worked in the past may not have been safe in the first place or are not safe or even useful in the present. The way we've always done things, may very well mess up the environment, oppress whole demographics, and so on. –

As I said conservative solutions are well understood but compromises.  The way we've always done things can sometimes have significant draw backs; however even those draw back are well understood.  That said, it is true conservative approaches tend to be safer but compromise solutions.  They can reliably be counted on to improve problems.  As you say though, all social progress are attributed to liberal thinkers.  Anti-Slavery, civil rights, workers' rights, anti trust, public education, social security, medicare and unions.  Here in the U.S. just about every founding father was a liberal, perhaps with the exception of Alexander Hamilton.  Of the 5 greatest presidents all were liberals.  Washington, Jefferson, Lincoln, T. Roosevelt, and F.D. Roosevelt.

They have no real meanings, more clearly their meaning is strongly context dependent without a clear objective version.
What is objective in politics, that is not right and left, but up and down.
A relative objective feature of dividing the political views into "left" and "right", that they might make the look and feel for inexperienced views, that these are equaly valuable. Thus, they try to disappear the objective moral values.
While the case is mostly not this. For example:

being a patriot is better than being a traitor
being good for everyone is better than being good only for a narrow group
doing things peacefully is better than doing things by force.

These are general, objective moral values, and dividing the actual views into "left" and "right" works only as a disguise for the worse side to play equal.
Better to not use the "left" and "right" words, instead use their correct name, even if it is not very trivial.

"Better than", not "better as". Also, "treacher" is apparently obsolete (I had to look it up); from the context, I assume you mean "traitor"?

@SteveMelnikoff Yes, thank you! I fix the post.

There is no objectivity when we talk human sciences. However, we need to 'tend' towards objectivity same way as perfection: ther4e is no such thing, however, we try aiming perfection...any othe rthing means you try less (are being mediocre -in the perfection example- or partial -in the objectivity example).
Said that, left and right are not absolute terms, but that does not mean cannot be described as relative ones.

@Natacha Current usage of these words is clearly an objective usage. Point is that the casuality of the relative terms makes them nearly unusable.
